# Convert string to long gcc version 4.6.2

Tags: c++, gcc

I need to convert string to long in **gcc version 4.6.2** JUST in this version.\
I googled it but all functions that I found is not available in the above version.

Regards

Comment: And what functions did you find?

Comment: stol() @Glapa and a few other functions

Comment: @DietmarKühl the accepted answer there is MS only.

Comment: @BoBTFish: the question certainly has answers which do work with the quoted compiler, even if the accepted answer does not (for example, the highest voted one does; the accepted answer doesn't always indicate the correct solution).